# How can i make the button fix at the top and the content collapse into it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried this code but when i click on the button the content collapses and the button moves down. I want the content to collapse and the button remains at the top inline with the other button.

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
#fixed {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
#block {
  border: solid #BDC3C7 1px;
  width: 360px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.ab {
  margin: 5px;
}
#demo {
  max-width: 350px;
  color: blue;
  border: solid #ddd 1px;
  padding: 5px 12px 0px 12px;
  margin: 2px -10px 2px 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.list {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee
}
.as {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template" target="_blank" class="navbar-brand">THINK</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#div1">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#div2">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#div3">Pricing</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="fixed">
      <div id="block">
        <div class="ab">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
          <div id="demo" class="collapse in">
            <ul class="as">
              <li class="list">hello</li>
              <li class="list">hi</li>
              <li class="list">hello</li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div id="block">
        <div class="ab">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">Simple collapsible</button>
          <div id="demo1" class="collapse in">
            <ul class="as">
              <li class="list">hello</li>
              <li class="list">hi</li>
              <li class="list">hello</li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the blocks a vertical align rule.

Also never duplicate an html id. Use classes instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <style>
    #fixed {
      margin-top: 60px;
    }
    /* Changed to class here */
    .block {
      border: solid #BDC3C7 1px;
      width: 360px;
      margin-left: 60px;
      display: inline-block;
      /* added vertical-align */
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .ab {
      margin: 5px;
    }
    #demo {
      max-width: 350px;
      color: blue;
      border: solid #ddd 1px;
      padding: 5px 12px 0px 12px;
      margin: 2px -10px 2px 0px;
      vertical-align: top;
      white-space: nowrap;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: left;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .list {
      list-style: none;
      border-bottom: solid 1px #eee
    }
    .as {
      margin: 0 0 10px 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template" target="_blank" class="navbar-brand">THINK</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#div1">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#div2">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#div3">Pricing</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="fixed">
      <!-- changed "block" from id to class here -->
      <div class="block">
        <div class="ab">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
          <div id="demo" class="collapse in">
            <ul class="as">
              <li class="list">hello</li>
              <li class="list">hi</li>
              <li class="list">hello</li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- changed "block" from id to class here -->
      <div class="block">
        <div class="ab">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">Simple collapsible</button>
          <div id="demo1" class="collapse in">
            <ul class="as">
              <li class="list">hello</li>
              <li class="list">hi</li>
              <li class="list">hello</li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```